Desarguesian geometry
I am studying Hilbert's Foundations of Geometry and I am a bit confused about the definition of a line in a space geometry constructed from a Desarguesian set of numbers. In the first edition, the definition is the following:

while in the second edition it is said that it is possibile to find a number $a$ such that $au'=u''$, $av'=v''$, $aw'=w''$, but this is actually the definition of parallel planes (if they also have at least one point in common, then they coincide)

Do you think there is a mistake in the second edition, or maybe I am missing something?
Thanks for any answer!
